# Match 4 four columns of data and get 5th column data against A and B column Row

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup, partial

I am looking to match 4 columns of data in Microsoft Excel.

For example below is the data which I am looking partial match and retrieve 5th column data against A and B column Row in ColumnF.

```
ColumnA      ColumnB              ColumnC        ColumnD        ColumnE    ColumnF
Ajay Ramana  Managing director    Farah Khan     associate at   458
Farah Khan   associate            John clayton   Director sr    458
```

I have huge list of data to be automated.

I want to partial match A against C and B against D.

something which does the above task.

Hope you understand friends.

Answer (score 0):

If by *partial match* you mean one string contains the other, I would suggest opening an ADO connection to the worksheet and issuing the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT Field5
FROM [Sheet1$]
WHERE '%' + Field1 + '%' LIKE '%' + Field3 + '%'
   OR '%' + Field2 + '%' LIKE '%' + Field4 + '%'
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32396594/111794) for an example of how to connect to an Excel workbook using ADO and issuing SQL statements.

And a better example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178913/combine-two-large-tables-into-one-table-based-on-unique-id/40276761#40276761).

Comment: Is it possible with Excel Macros>. Please help with a macro code.I do not have knowledge on ADO or SQL.

Comment: @KumarK Added link.

Comment: @KumarK Added additional link.